# How to run a java project with cmd without installing netbeans

Tags: java, batch-file, javafx, cmd

Im trying to run a javafx project file by using the cmd in another computer that does not have netbeans on it.

Any suggestion on how to run my project file without installing netbeans (the source file is rather complicated)

And what does a batch-file means?

Comment: What are you starting with? Compiled code? Jar file? Source code?

Comment: jar file and source code

Comment: Java command line tools [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/) ->  Basic tools [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/#basic) -> `java` command [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html)

Answer (score 0):

With the jar file you can do either

```
java -jar path/to/jar/file
```

if the jar file has a manifest with a `Main-Class` entry, or

```
java -cp path/to/jar/file MainClass
```

where `MainClass` is the fully-qualified name of your `Application` subclass.

Comment: Note that you need the full name of your main class, including the package name: `my.package.MainClass`

Comment: Yes, thanks for clarifying that (I kind of assumed it was understood). Edited accordingly.